# How to update a vargs to send to printf

Tags: c

I have the following code where I format a message that has been passed via a logger:

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, level);

// pop the msg and do some string replaces
char *msg    = va_arg(args, char*);
ssize_t len  = str_replace(tmp, "%(msg)s", msg, output, 1024);

// now how to get it 'back in' so I can print it?'
// msg = output

vfprintf(stderr, output, args);
```

The above code prints nothing, as it seems to have 'popped' the `msg` without me placing the updated msg back in there. What would be a possible way to do this?

Comment: It is not quite clear wat you want to do. It looks as if you were writing your own format parser with a single optional argument. Perhaps you could post the log function signature and a typical use? If you just have one possible extra argument (`%(msg)s`), you may not need `vfprintf` at all. (When writing `printf`-like functions, the format string is usually the last non-variable argument. That may also be an option.)

Comment: `vfprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);` ? Are you sure you are using the right variable?

Comment: If you just want to replace `%(msg)s` with message and have no other format replacements, you can just `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg)`, of course. I suspect that you try to use varargs here where you shouldn't.

Comment: After everything else gets fixed, note that you are missing the `va_end`, and reusing `args` after having been modified without an intervening `va_start` or `va_copy`.

Comment: @dxiv I see. Actually, I think I can use the function as is, and just use `output` as the `const char` format part of `vfprintf`.

Comment: Perhaps. It look all very brittle. You could also `vsnprintf` your message to a string buffer `buf` first and then replace `"%s(msg)s`" with `buf`. If format is the last non-vararg, you can use gcc attributes or Microsoft's SAL to check consistency between format specifiers and arguments, which I find valuable.

Comment: what does str_replace do? share the definition or at least prototype. and try all of above.

Comment: @CallMeRK `ssize_t 
str_replace (const char* input_str, const char* from, const char* to, char* output_buffer, size_t max_size)` I suppose it would be like doing a `str.replace("This", "That")` in python or another language.

Comment: @MOehm cool, would you want to show how that might be done?

Comment: first of all, check if the code till str_replace part is doing what you expect by adding couple printf.
printf("%s\n",msg);
......
printf("%s\n",output);

... 
if that prints what you expected. Then we can go further.

Comment: Sure. I've posted a answer. (I've had to extrapolate a bit and guessed what you try to achieve. I think this is more or less what you were going for.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling with the format string, you could print the variadic arguments passed to the log function to a string first, then print that string with a regular `fprintf` via the `%s` format.

You haven't posted your function signature, but it looks as if you passed the format string as first variadic argument. That's unusual. I've changed the signature so that the format string is the last non-variadic arg. That's common and it also opens up the possibility to chech your format strings for correctness. (See below.)

Here's an example implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

enum {
    FATAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, NLEVEL
};

void say(int level, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    static const char *templates[NLEVEL] = {
        "\033[1m!!! FATAL: %s !!!\033[0m\n",
        "ERROR: %s\n",
        "Warning: %s\n",
        "%s Just sayin'.\n"
    };

    const char *tmp;
    char output[1024];
    va_list args;
    
    // print arguments to temporary string

    va_start(args, fmt);    
    vsnprintf(output, sizeof(output), fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    
    // find and print template string with message
    
    if (level < 0) level = 0;
    if (level >= NLEVEL) level = INFO;

    tmp = templates[level];
    fprintf(stderr, tmp, output);
    
    va_end(args);
    
    if (level == FATAL) exit(1);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 6;
    int b = 7;    
    double Tmin = -273.15;

    say(INFO, "%d * %d == %d.", a, b, a * b);
    say(INFO, "The %s is %s.", "apple", "red and juicy");

    say(WARNING, "Temperature falls below Tmin (%gC)", Tmin);
    say(ERROR, "That should %s have happened.",
        (rand() % 2) ? "never" : "not really");
    
    say(FATAL, "Out of coffee!");

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, you can make your logging functions safer and let the compiler check the validity of format strings. GCC and Clang do this with arguments, the Microsoft compiler does it with SAL, the Source-code Annotation Language. Other compilers may have their own method to do such checks. (More likely, they just emulate one of the GC or MS systems.)

With a little macro dance in the header you can cater for both variants:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define PRINTF_FMT _Printf_format_string_
#endif

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
#define PRINTF_ARGS(IFMT, IARGS) __attribute__((format(printf, IFMT, IARGS)))
#endif

#ifndef PRINTF_ARGS
#define PRINTF_ARGS(IFMT, IARGS)
#endif

#ifndef PRINTF_FMT
#define PRINTF_FMT
#endif

void say(int level, PRINTF_FMT const char *fmt, ...) PRINTF_ARGS(2, 3);
```

Now a call like this:

```
say(WARNING, "Meta: Wrong formt for %d.", ~0ull);
```

warns you about the wrong format specifier.